# Kickstart Price slider in front page

Tags: drupal-7, facet, faceted-search

Can any one say that how i show my `kickstart` price slider in front page.

I read many reference but still at no where .
I use the `multiblock` module but the block produced is only shows in the search page.

Then I also try through view . I create another facet block using `facet api` but there is no option for changing the display widget.

is there any way or i am missing something .

Any help is most appreciable .
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it myself i create a facet block with price field and a search block of index type which will show the facet in every where the search page will shown .i restricted it for only front page .Then it works for me.